# Filter year for dates prior to 1900

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell with `30/09/0201` as the date. How can I apply a year filter for this column like this

Note: since the year is <1900, i am not able to apply `=DATE()` function.

Comment: Use a helper column with `=--RIGHT(A1,4)` and filter on that.

Comment: You would need helper columns as mentioned above ^^^. to sort not just based on year bust as well as on months and days so it will be sorted chronologically.

Answer (score 2):

Only one helper-column would be needed since not only dates with a numerical value can be sorted but date as text can also be sorted from high to low since 0-9 (as text) still would be sorted the same way as if it were a number (order is kept the same as a character, i.e. a-z|A-Z|0-9, etc.).

[image]

> =RIGHT(A2;4)&RIGHT(LEFT(A2;5);2)&LEFT(A2;2)

[image]

Let me know if it doesn't work out (or if I'm wrong with my explanation @the rest)